# How can I to create a table and create 2 columns for each row on the fly

Tags: javascript

How can I to create a table and create 2 columns for each row and each column will hold a checkbox from the variable Time and assign the table to an object property.

var Time will have string in the form of following examples:
08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;09:00 AM - 10:00 AM;10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
09:30 AM - 10:30 AM;11:30 AM - 12:30 PM

If there is Semicolon in the variable Time string then it should break the string into pieces and then create a checkbox for each piece.

For example in the case of "08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;09:00 AM - 10:00 AM;10:00 AM - 11:00 AM" then it should create a table with 2 rows and 2 columns and first row will have “08:00 AM - 09:00 AM” in the first column and “09:00 AM - 10:00 AM” in the second column and second row will have “10:00 AM - 11:00 AM" in the first column and noting in the second column.

In other words BookArray[i-1][2] will hold a different table with rows and each rows will have 2 columns and each column will have a checkbox for each record.

```
for(var i = 0; i < gAssessorsArray.length; i++) 
{                           
    var Time = gAssessorsArray[i].Time; 
    var CurrentTable;

    BookArray[i] = new Array();
    BookArray[i][0] = gAssessorsArray[i].ID;    
    BookArray[i][1] = '<input type="checkbox" id="bk_' + gAssessorsArray[i].ID + '" value="' + gAssessorsArray[i].Name + '" onchange="BookAppointment(this)" />';           
    BookArray[i][2] = CurrentTable;                                                     
}
```

Comment: BookArray[i-1] with i === 0 will create a -1 index.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? From what I read, you want a table with 2 columns and fill it with infos, am I right?

Comment: @Will I fixed the index Issue.

Comment: @JeffNoel I want to create a table with 2 column (each column will have a checkbox depends on the Time variable) for each loop index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give this a try:

### My setup

**HTML**

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var gAssessorsArray = [];
gAssessorsArray[0] = {
    ID: 0,
    Name: 'Robert',
    Time: '12:00'
};
gAssessorsArray[1] = {
    ID: 1,
    Name: 'Chocolate',
    Time: '9:00;4:35;12:30 - 1:00;00:00'
};
gAssessorsArray[2] = {
    ID: 2,
    Name: 'Hot Chocolate',
    Time: '3:00;4:35;5:30'
};
```

---

### Solution [[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/Juhdr/12/)

```js
var table = "";
var checkboxes = "";
for (var i = 0; i < gAssessorsArray.length; i++) {
    var times = gAssessorsArray[i].Time.split(';');


    if (times.length < 3) {
        times[0] = times[1] == undefined ? '<td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[0] + '</td>' : '<td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[0] + '</td>'
        times[1] = times[1] == undefined ? '' : '<td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[1] + '</td>';

        checkboxes = (times[1] != undefined && times[1].length > 1) ? '<input type="checkbox" />' : '';

        table = '<table><thead><tr><th colspan="2">' + gAssessorsArray[i].Name + '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        table += '<tr id="' + gAssessorsArray[i].ID + '">' + times[0] + times[1] + '</tr></tbody></table>';
    } else {
        if (times.length % 2 == 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
                times[j] = j % 2 == 0 ? '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[j] + '</td>' : '<td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[j] + '</td></tr>';
            }
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
                if (j == times.length - 1) {
                    times[times.length - 1] = '<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[times.length - 1] + '</td></tr>';
                    continue;
                }
                times[j] = (j % 2 == 0) ? ('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[j] + '</td>') : ('<td><input type="checkbox"/>' + times[j] + '</td></tr>');

            }

        }

        table = '<table><thead><tr><th colspan="2">' + gAssessorsArray[i].Name + '</th></tr></thead><tbody>' + times.join("") + '</tbody></table>';
    }


    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML += table;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But In the case of Time: '9:00;4:35;10:00;12:00' then it should create 2 rows and each row will have 2 columns so my table will have number of rows depends on the Time separated by ";" but each row will always have 2 columns.

Comment: @AsifAkhtar Oh I get it, I'll work on this after my lunch break !

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Though I would like to create all rows with 2 columns in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
for ( ... each "gAssessorsArray"
  var time = arrayItem.Time;
  var cells = someCodeThatSplitsTime(time); // each "cell" would be a string
                                            // representing the cell content
                                            // i.e. "08:00 - 09:00"
  var table = $("<table />");
  var row = $("<tr />"), col = 0;
  table.append(row);
  for ( ... each "cells"
     if (col == 2) {
       col = 0;
       row = $("<tr />");
       table.append(row);
     }
     var chk = $("<input type='checkbox />'");
     var span = $("<span />");
     span.text(cell); // 08:00 - 09:00
     var colEl = $("<td />");
     colEl.append(chk);
     colEl.append(span);
     row.append(colEl);
     col++;
  }

  arrayItem.Table = table
```

Assuming of course that you have jQuery at your disposal. Otherwise, you'll need to change every $ function with the corresponding DOM function.